# Checkbox auto checked based on value from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

how can I auto check the checkbox based on the value from the database? I have the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CarModel" value="Yes"  ($row[CarModel]==Audi? 'checked' : '') >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CarModel" value="Yes"  <?php echo ($row['CarModel'] == 'Audi' ) ? 'checked' : NULL ; ?> >
```